# how to insert the value into a table type through a select statement in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I am a beginner in Oracle. I created the table type as like as follows:

```
TYPE metertable IS TABLE OF pseb.metermaster.meterid%type;
```

I dnt know how to insert the value into that table type. I need to store the whole resultset of the following query into the table type.

```
select  distinct(meterid) 
from pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper 
where feederid in (select distinct (fm.FeederID) 
                   from pseb.feedermaster fm,pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper cfm
                   where fm.substationid=v_v_type
                   and cfm.feederid=fm.feederid
                   and cfm.FeederID>0)
 and meterid >0
 order by meterid;
```

Help me to do that.

Comment: you want to insert the data that you get from this query ?
select  distinct(meterid) from pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper where feederid in (select distinct (fm.FeederID) from pseb.feedermaster fm,pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper cfm where fm.substationid=v_v_type and cfm.feederid=fm.feederid and cfm.FeederID>0) and meterid >0 order by meterid;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BULK COLLECT to select the data into a variable of that type:

```
declare
  mt metertable;
begin
  select  distinct(meterid) 
  bulk collect into mt
  from pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper 
  where feederid in (select distinct (fm.FeederID) 
                     from pseb.feedermaster fm,pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper cfm
                     where fm.substationid=v_v_type
                     and cfm.feederid=fm.feederid
                     and cfm.FeederID>0)
  and meterid >0
  order by meterid;

  -- Now use mt...
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this code help me :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    TYPE t_bulk_collect_test_tab IS TABLE OF bulk_collect_test%ROWTYPE;
    l_tab     t_bulk_collect_test_tab;
    l_cursor  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    -- Way 1
    OPEN l_cursor FOR 'SELECT * FROM bulk_collect_test';
    FETCH l_cursor
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;
    CLOSE l_cursor; 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Dynamic FETCH  : ' || l_tab.count);


    -- Way 2
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM bulk_collect_test' BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Dynamic EXECUTE: ' || l_tab.count);
END;
/
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_dynamic.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
type tab_type is table of consumerfeedermetermapper%rowtype;
tab_t tab_type;
begin

select  distinct(meterid) bulk collect into tab_t
from pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper 
where feederid in (select distinct (fm.FeederID) 
                   from pseb.feedermaster fm,pseb.consumerfeedermetermapper cfm
                   where fm.substationid=v_v_type
                   and cfm.feederid=fm.feederid
                   and cfm.FeederID>0)
 and meterid >0
 order by meterid;
 end;
```

You can use the above code